# The permissions granted to the user are insufficient to perform this operation. (RsAccessDenied)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I need some help with this error: The user does not have the required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and that the Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been handled.

Im executing ie as administrator.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: which permission do you have in SSRS and in that concretely folder?

Comment: Thanks for your response. In this two folders i have total control for my user (admin user):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.SQLEXPRESS\Reporting Services\ReportManager

and

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.SQLEXPRESS\Reporting Services\ReportServer

In SSRS database my user is the dbo

Answer (score 2):

By your comment I believe you are looking for NTFS permission and not the Reporting Services permissions. Try this:

1. 'Run as' administrator IE and open your http://localhost/Reports (or whatever is the URL)
2. In the top right corner click on 'Site Setting' (http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Settings.aspx)
3. Check the 'Security' settings (http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Settings.aspx?SelectedSubTabId=SecurityLinkID)
4. After you set the permissions how you need, relaunch the browser without with your normal account and try it.

For more information about how to set the permissions read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156034(v=sql.110).aspx

> **To add a user or group to a system role**
>
> 1. Start Report Manager (SSRS).
> 2. Click Site Settings.
> 3. Click Security.
> 4. Click New Role Assignment.
> 5. In Group or user name, enter a Windows domain user or group account
>      in this format: \. If you are using forms
>      authentication or custom security, specify the user or group account
>      in the format that is correct for your deployment.
> 6. Select a system role, and then click OK. *[Roles are cumulative, so if you select both System Administrator and System User, a user or
>      group will be able to perform the tasks in both roles.]*
> 7. Repeat to create assignments for additional users or groups.
>
> **To add a user or group to an item role**
>
> 1. Start Report Manager and locate the report item for which you want
>      to add a user or group.
> 2. Hover over the item, and click the drop-down arrow.
> 3. In the drop-down menu, click Security.
> 4. Click New Role Assignment.
>
> *Note If an item currently inherits security from a parent item, click Edit Item Security in the toolbar to change the security settings.
>   Then click New Role Assignment.*
>
> 5. In Group or user name, enter a Windows domain user or group account
>      in this format: \. If you are using forms
>      authentication or custom security, specify the user or group account
>      in the format that is correct for your deployment.
> 6. Select one or more role definitions that describe how the user or
>      group should access the item, and then click OK.
> 7. Repeat to create assignments for additional users or groups.